# CMake-generated Makefile does not contain target

Tags: cmake

I'm using G++ MinGW for compiling. My Files :

> main.cpp, linkedList.cpp, linkedList.h

My CMake file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0)
project (Tutorial)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -std=c++11")
enable_testing()

include_directories(include)
add_executable(Tutorial 
main.cpp
linkedList.cpp
linkedList.h
)

add_test(Tutorial tutorial)
```

The exact compile error from generated Makefile :

```
mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../linkedList.h', needed by 'CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/main.cpp.obj'.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[Gist for CMake generated Makefile](https://gist.github.com/general656/655454f9085efe86df3d)

Comment: linkedList.h is an header, not a source file. Remove it from list of source file

Comment: Thank you, I just saw it somewhere in stackoverflow as an answer so I supposed that I could add it there.

Comment: That generated makefile doesn't mention `linkedList.h` anywhere.

Comment: What's the command you are executing? Is it `make Tutorial`?

Comment: @usr1234567 In this question I'm not using Linux so I'm not executing any command (which I suppose you suggest), also thank you for the Title edit. I'll try make better titles next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You target is `Tutorial`, not `../LinkedList.h`

Go to your build directory and execute

```
make Tutorial
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the term "target" ? Also I'm using CMake for this reason, so I do not have to execute any commands because I'm currently using Windows (which is without terminal) and I want to know how to make efficiently Makefiles in Windows. I just don't know what this error means exactly.
Also I think you misunderstood my question. I did not execute "make ../LinkedList.h" if that's what you say, I just made the CMakeFile you see then I go to CMake GUI and these errors appear.

Comment: First: Try what Garf365 suggested and remove `linkedList.h` from your CMakeLists.txt. And it cannot be, that you only execute CMake-Gui, because the error indicates clearly, that `mingw32-make` emits the error. So at least you have compiled it after running CMake, maybe through an IDE or similar.